# What is the meaning of "war capacity of an aircraft"?

Tags: usage, phrases

I read a sentence in "The Hindu" which was:

> The photocopying of sensitive documents on the war capacity of the Rafale combat aircraft and their leakage is a conspiracy.

What is the meaning of "war capacity" here?
According to paradoxwikis.com, it means - War Capacity is a measure for how capable a nation is of continuing and possible winning a war. But that doesn't fit here.

Comment: I think there might be an element of "Indian English" in the cited usage. To my ear, ***capability*** (or more likely, pluralized ***capabilities***) sounds more natural. But that's just my opinion, nothing to back it up.

Comment: Can you find a link to the as-published documents?  Now that China and Pakistan can see them, their contents are not exactly secret anymore.  [Another article](https://www.thehindu.com/news/national/secret-papers-on-rafale-deal-stolen/article26450436.ece) in *The Hindu* suggests that the most valuable secrets in the documents were the prices of the aircraft, rather than the capabilities of the aircraft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

War capacity means military capabilities or potential. The capabilities of a warplane might include technical details like range, maximum speed, amount of bombs or missiles it can carry, what electronic equipment it carries, etc.

Answer (score -2):

"[Payload](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/payload)" is probably what is meant by "war capacity of an aircraft".

There is a trade-off between payload (what, and how much, can be carried by an aircraft) and fuel.  More fuel allows the plane to go faster and/or further.